# Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge (HVZK) composability

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Let protocol A and protocol B be HVZK proof systems. If we construct a protocol C composed of protocol A and protocol B, will it be HVZK as well? Is there some formal proof in the literature regarding this?

Comment: Composed how? Sequentially? Parallel? Arbitrarily?

Comment: Arbitrarily, @Maeher.